# Rails Association not working (as I expect it to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, models

New to Rails and trying to test an association I have. I've got these three interrelated models: Animal, Order, and Line. Basically, Lines belong to Orders belong to Animals. And I want the animal show page to list all the orders associated with that animal and the line (singular, for now) associated with that order.

Here are the model files.

animal.rb:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :breed, :photo, :animal_type 
  has_many :orders
end
```

line.rb

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  attr_accessible :notes, :units
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal
  attr_accessible :status, :lines_attributes, :animal_id

  has_many :lines

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines
end
```

What I'm trying to do is show all the lines and orders associated with a given animal on the animal show view. Here's my show view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="pull-left"> 
  <h2><span style="font-size:80%"> Animal Name: </span><%= @animal.name %></h2>
</div>

<br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Type of Animal</th>
    <th>Breed</th>
    <th>Photo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @animal.animal_type %></td>
    <td><%= @animal.breed %></td>
    <td><%= @animal.photo %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<h2>Associated Orders</h2>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <th>Order Status</th>
    <th>Line Notes</th>
    <th>Line Units</th>
  <tr>
  <%= render 'orderlist' %>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_animal_path(@animal) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', animals_path %>
```

And, finally, here's that orderlist helper

```
<% @animal.orders.each do |o| %>
    <tr>
        <th><%= o.id %></th>
        <th><%= o.status %></th>
        <th><%= o.lines.notes %></th>
        <th><%= o.lines.units %></th>
    </tr>
<%end%>
```

This throws up an error when I visit the show page, though, saying

```
undefined method `notes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9259c5da80>
```

If I delete .notes, then it says the same for units. If I delete both (and leave o.lines), the page loads just fine and lists in those two table cells all the information (line id, line units, line notes) of the relevant lines. So it's definitely finding the right model object, but it's not letting me call the specific attribute.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Stumped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method "notes", (and "units") on a *collection* of lines associated with the order. You may be try to call those methods for each line in the order. To output the notes for each line in the view, a rough rewrite could be:

```
<% @animal.orders.each do |o| %>
  <tr>
    <th><%= o.id %></th>
    <th><%= o.status %></th>
    <th><%= o.lines.map(&:notes).join('. ') %></th>
    <th><%= o.lines.map(&:units).join('. ') %></th>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Cool. I've never seen that .map method. The idea is it's basically listing the notes of each line, joined by a ". "? What's the & about here? Could I alternately do another o.lines.each do |l| within the loop and then create a new table line for each line (to accomodate my shortly adding more lines per order)?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map - yes you could parse each o.lines and treat the separately

Answer (score 1):

Look at your Order class:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :lines 
end
```

And your view line:

`o.lines.notes`

`o.lines` is currently a set of lines that belong to the Order.

As @rossta has posted while I'm typing this, you can concatenate the noted of all the lines.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't really think of that, cause the current association was more of a has_one, but I made it "has_many" cause I was planning to change that.